# Angular and Reactive form arrays setting a form ontrol value inside form array giving error of must supply a value for form control name

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular7, formarray

I need to set a specific form control of a reactive form array to a value.
 I am using the following:

```
(<FormArray>this.formGroup.get('test')).at(i).setValue(oldFr);
```

Where `i` is the index where the change should be done, and `oldFr` the value to be set.

But I forgot that there is multiple form controls in each index. The form control I need to set is called `formControlName="fr"`.

I tried:

(this.formGroup.get('test')).at(i).controls['fr'].setValue(oldFr);

But I had the following error:

> ERROR Error: Must supply a value for form control with name: 'fr'

And

> Cannot read property 'at' of null

How can I set a value of a form control residing inside array of controls ?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] reproducing the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you have a FormGroup with a key containing a FormArray which itself contains an array of FormGroups.

```
const formGroup = new FormGroup({
  test: new FormArray([
    new FormGroup({
      fr: new FormControl('')
    })
  ])
})

formGroup.get('test').at(0).get('fr').patchValue(oldFr)
```

Comment: I didn't understand exactly the difference between both `patchValue` and `setValue`. Can you explain more ?

Comment: By the way, both `setValue` and `patchValue` worked with your code.

Comment: @alim1990 you're right. The two methods appear to be the same. I had thought that `patchValue` could be used to set an individual control's value, while `setValue` was for setting the value of an entire FormGroup, but I appear to be mistaken. I deleted that part of my answer.

Comment: @alim1990
setValue : you need to set all fields.
PatchValue: you can set only one field.

Comment: I'm going to augment @YohannDanielCarter's answer by emphasizing that with `setValue` you *need* to set all fields and with `patchValue` you *may* set only one field (but can also set multiple fields).